# Unable to run my JavaFX project on Mac with JavaFX and JDK-15 Intellij. Error java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx, java-15

Hi I've been trying to set up JavaFX on my mac and I followed the tutorial layed out on their website. However, after following through everything, it keeps giving me an error and fails to compile with a message saying access denied in my other accounts Music folder for some reason. I would greatly appreciate any help!

[image: Screenshot of my VM options configuration]

[image: The error that it keeps giving me]

Comment: @matt I am using the guest account on my mac but I have full read and write privilege on this account. So it is referring to the other account on my system. I can build and run a non-javafx project.

Comment: Idk what the issue was but I ended up fixing it when I tried running it from my main account.

Comment: Please post an Answer to your own Question and accept it to mark the issue resolved.

Comment: In the future, be sure to include text that might help others when searching. I edited your title to include your particular error type.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're logged into MacOS as "Guest" user. Since your module-info.java is under the Advait user's directory, the "Guest" user would not have access to read this file.

There are two options to fix this.

1. Log in as the Advait user
2. Change permissions on the project directory to allow other users to read/write (not recommended)